# How to get all users of a group in ADFS claim

Tags: adfs, adfs3.0, adfs2.1

How to get all users of a group in ADFS claim, what is configuration steps in ADFS and how to get all users of a group

Comment: Why would you want all the users for a group. This use case does not make a lot of sense. You may want to know if the user belongs to a specific set of groups in the claims so that the app can do authorization, but getting all users in a group is more of a directory lookup and not through claims.

Comment: i have a feature in app using that i am assigning users to specific task, so i need all users, how can i get all users?